# Software Updater removed laptop-mode-tools after upgrading

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, power-management

After upgrading today to 14.04.3 via terminal, the Software Updater removed laptop-mode-tools saying it was an old package.

Has laptop-mode-tools become obsolete in 14.04.3 or should I just re-install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reinstall `laptop-mode-tools`

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

The package is still present and also available for Utopic, Vivid and Wily.

Comment: Thanks. I could see I could reinstall it, but was wondering whether it had been superseded by a different package.